# Synology NAS upload speed very slow

Tags: lan, nas, synology

When I copy huge files from my NAS to anywhere in my LAN, the upload speed is not constant. I experience that expecially on HD movies, which are hanging. This is the network graph:

[image: NAS network graph]

The NAS is connected to a Netgear GB switch. No matter which target I use to copy the data, the network graph is always similar. I also tried to restart the Switch and the NAS, with no success.

Any idea?

+++ Update +++

Please find 3 new images attached, taken at the same time, showing Disk read speed and network upload, and CPU:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That seems pretty regular - is the drop in bandwidth coinciding with when you finish writing one file, and start writing the next? If so, thats actually really common, as the remote server blocks while it actually finishes writing the file to disk.

Comment: No, this is the example graph on streaming a multi GB file.

Comment: Weird. Can you graph disk IO as well? See if something goes crazy during those gaps? Try to correlate that graph with something else - CPU spikes, disk, memory consumption... those gaps are WAY too regular for most failures I see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added two images. Indeed, the disk read speed is corresponding with the network speed. The SMART status of both RAID volumes is okay.

Comment: Very interesting. Looks like something is blocking the disk - seek time, maybe? Might be writing logs or something elsewhere on disk at those specific times. I'd check for cron jobs and file access during those gaps. Something _else_ is going on thats blocking your transfer speed.

Comment: ok, I'll take a look at the looks. Meanwhile, I also added the CPU graph

Comment: I can reproduce it wich streaming MKV files - this causes the typical graph pattern. So it seems to be a video codec related issue.

Comment: It looks like cpu is spiking during those gaps. I would find out what process is causing that

Comment: This seems like a regular streaming behavior: Player is caching the first e.g. 10 seconds, then waits until the cache is nearly empty, then loads the next 10 seconds, then waits,...
It would be a very uncommon behavior for uncached copying (from or to the NAS) of files, but not for streaming. Try [CrystalDiskMark](https://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html) or similar benchmarking tools.

Comment: Pretty sure this person figured out the issue sometime in the last 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

I had this behaviour with a Gigabit setup, where two devices didn't quite agree on what a Jumbo frame was or how to handle it properly.

I had to work around the problem by lowering all involved devices' MTU setting to the base Ethernet level of 1500 (in the end, I replaced one of the devices).

Answer (score -3):

You might have "green" hard drives installed, which periodically spin up and spin down to conserve a minute amount of energy. Not practical or useful in a NAS. Personally, not useful anywhere for me.

Comment: Which drives would that be? I have not heard or seen anyone claiming that before, nor have I ever experienced such a behavior myself. If you think about WD Green: that's not how this works - that's not how any of this works.